# MySQL user variable addition: '+1' return '+2'

Tags: mysql

I'm coding a movie search engine called [Movieovo](http://www.movieovo.com), I want to select the top 5 rows (movie links) from each group (movie title), but I met a problem in this SQL query:

```
SELECT link_movie_id, link_id,
        @num := if(@link_movie_id = link_movie_id, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
        @link_movie_id := link_movie_id as dummy
        FROM link GROUP BY link_movie_id, link_id HAVING row_number <= 5 LIMIT 30
```

Result: ( Too many characters so I upload as an image  )
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTzhT.png

You can see "row_number" does not +1 each time

I tried directly in MySQL command line shows me the same results, can anyone help me? I have already wasted 5 hours in this problem..

Comment: Edt your question with some sample data?

Comment: This is strange, what happens if you try @ num := if(@ link_movie_id = link_movie_id, @ num + 0.5, 1) as row_number

Comment: Add `JOIN (SELECT @num:=0) x ` to get @num initialized.

Comment: I join another Table and it works too. It's strange. However, my search engine has been online, thank you everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing link_movie_id by 1, but you are grouping by link_movie_id and link_id. With the effect, for some link_movie_id, there are multiple values of link_id in the result. If you are want to get what you are looking for, either group by a single field, or increment it based on a concatenated combination of link_movie_id and link_id.